# With color picker limit the colors available to grayscale

Tags: jquery, colors

With color picker http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/, how can I limit the number of colors to just using the grayscale slider?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want to force your user to select a shade of gray or to limit the number of lightness levels the user can choose? The former can be done with some CSS, the latter needs a `change` callback.

Comment: as an observation from the one given in the link.. it would seem that 'grayscale' would mean that the RGB would be equal?

check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835753/convert-grayscale-value-to-rgb-representation

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My intent is switch to grayscale and take the rgb value

Comment: the link you provide is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to limit to **greyscale** values, the rgb model must be like:

```
x = [0, 255]

rgb(x, x, x)
```

For example:

```
.elem { background-color: rgb(122, 122, 122); }
```

or in hexadecimal, as css # notation, the values must follow:

```
x = [0, 9][a, f]
y = [0, 9][a, f]

#xyxyxy
```

For example:

```
.elem { background-color: #e1e1e1; }
```