# convert a 2D matrix into a 3D matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 2D matrix which has the size `65536 × 1`, if I want to convert it to a 3D in MATLAB, first I should convert it to a `256 × 256`, and then that `256 × 256` into an 3D.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: How is it supposed to work? 6656*3 = 19968 elements, whereas 256*256 = 65536 elements!? To change dimensions, use `reshape`

Comment: sry, I made a mistake, the input matrix is 65536*1

Comment: ...and how big do you want the 3D matrix to be?

Comment: 256*256*256, I guess.. I have a gray image and I'm trying to change it to a rgb image

Comment: someone said I could use: rgbimage = grayimage(:,:,[1 1 1]); but I dont know how to use it

Comment: Ah...it makes a lot more sense now. You just want to convert a greyscale image into an RGB image. Why don't you just ask that? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert grayscale value to RGB representation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835753/convert-grayscale-value-to-rgb-representation)

Comment: yes, but I've wrote my program codes, and there's just one last step remaining and that's the question I asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your greyscale image (that somehow has been vectorized) into an RGB image, just copy the greyscale intensities into the RGB layers:

```
%// first, reshape
img = reshape(img, 256, 256);

%// then, copy
img = repmat(img, [1 1 3]);
```

Comment: `img` is... why not simply try it yourself?

Comment: @user3223551: I've updated my answer to meet your demands. For future reference, this is a typical example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); please ask about your *original* problem, not about problems you encounter during your attempt to solve your original problem. Include your attempted solution, and why that fails.