# map grayscale values to RGB values in image

Tags: python, image, mapping, rgb, grayscale

Let us consider a grayscale value with values in the range of [0, 255]. How can we efficiently map each value to a RGB value?

So far, I have come up with the following implementation:

```
# function for colorizing a label image:
def label_img_to_color(img):
    label_to_color = {
    0: [128, 64,128],
    1: [244, 35,232],
    2: [ 70, 70, 70],
    3: [102,102,156],
    4: [190,153,153],
    5: [153,153,153],
    6: [250,170, 30],
    7: [220,220,  0],
    8: [107,142, 35],
    9: [152,251,152],
    10: [ 70,130,180],
    11: [220, 20, 60],
    12: [255,  0,  0],
    13: [  0,  0,142],
    14: [  0,  0, 70],
    15: [  0, 60,100],
    16: [  0, 80,100],
    17: [  0,  0,230],
    18: [119, 11, 32],
    19: [81,  0, 81]
    }

img_height, img_width = img.shape

img_color = np.zeros((img_height, img_width, 3))
for row in range(img_height):
    for col in range(img_width):
        label = img[row, col]
        img_color[row, col] = np.array(label_to_color[label])
return img_color
```

However, as you can see it is not efficient as there are two "for" loops.

This question was also asked in [Convert grayscale value to RGB representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835753/convert-grayscale-value-to-rgb-representation), but no efficient implementation was suggested.

Comment: Having two for loops is not inefficient.  It is logically impossible to index over a two-dimensional data structure without having two for loops.  What is inefficient is converting each label_to_color list into a np.array *inside* the for loops.  Why not initialize your `label_to_color` list with np.array objects (instead of Python lists) in the `label_img_to_color` function?

Comment: actually it turned out there is an efficient way to do that. Please check out the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, I believe the code I provided in the answer implements some kind of double for loop on a lower level. However, for loops in python are highly inefficient compared to using numpy boolean indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient way of doing that instead of a double for loop over all pixels could be:

```
rgb_img = np.zeros((*img.shape, 3)) 
for key in label_to_color.keys():
    rgb_img[img == key] = label_to_color[key]
```

Comment: the color map is fixed, so using a colormap from OpenCV is not the solution. Your solution converts a grayscale image to RGB. There is no conversion of pixel values according to label_to_color table.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. You made my day. It is super fast. Only Python complained about *img.shape saying it is a syntax error so I used img_height, img_width = img.shape
 rgb_img = np.zeros((img_height, img_width, 3)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote nearly the same question, and during question review I found @MattSt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222888/276168). For posterity, here is the question I was about to ask:

**How to convert a grayscale image to RGB one, given a pixel mapping function using NumPy?**

I have a dictionary which maps labels to colors. But I don't know how to efficiently convert a 2D label map to 2D color image, using the provided mapping. This works:

```py
label_to_color = {0: [0, 0, 0], 1: [255, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 255], 3: [0, 128, 0]}

def label_map_to_color(label_map):
    color_map = np.empty(
        (label_map.shape[0], label_map.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8
    )
    for k in range(label_map.shape[0]):
        for i in range(label_map.shape[1]):
            color_map[k, i, :] = label_to_color[(label_map[k, i])]
    return color_map
```

But there must be a more efficient way to accomplish this?