# How can i convert simple shape bitmap to vector ( geometry)

Tags: wpf, vector, bitmap

I would to know if it's possible to convert a simple bitmap to a geometry object

Comment: That's not a simple process (and a quick search didn't provide any promising SDKs). Look up edge detection and raster to vector conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can using tracing. [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) is an open source bitmap-to-vector tracer library.

However, bitmap tracing is imperfect; for high-quality vector image, line tracer is generally only used to do the initial tracing, which would later be hand-tweaked. [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), an open source vector image editor, provides built-in support for tracing (internally using potrace).

Comment: source bitmap will be simple shape and black and white, i just need all the conversion to be automatic : people load a bitmap and i store a geomtry object , the goal is to extrude these shape to a 3d cone

Comment: simple black and white image can be easily traced using potrace (in fact, they're the ONLY thing that can be traced, color images need to be somehow converted to black-and-white before you can trace them).

Comment: it seam that Inkscape can convert colored bitmap to vectors ... is there any way to doing that in command line

Comment: @guillaume not with the potrace cmd line. What I've seen online is to split the rgb channels, and trace them separately. My guess is that you'd then use some kind of xml parser to get the paths of each channel, set their fills to their respective colors, set their transparency to that of the rgb color matrix (.2126 * R^gamma + .7152 * G^gamma + .0722 * B^gamma - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity) for each respective channel, ie the red channel traced paths would be filled red, with transparency value of 21.26%.