# Grayscale image converting Turbo C++

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I am trying to convert an RGB image to a grayscale image. The RGB image is 160*120*4, while my grayscale is 160*120*1. However, it just give me plain black instead of what I want and takes a very long time.

This is what I wrote, please advise. Thanks

```
int i, j, sum;
Image = new unsigned char [ 160 * 120 * 1 ];
for( int j = 0; j < 120; j++ ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < 160; i++ ) {
    sum=0;
        sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
        sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
        sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
        sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
        *Image = sum/4;

        PaintBox2->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ] = *Image;
        Image++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turbo C++ doesn't even exists anymore. I suggest you move to Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 and get an *Express* edition, which is free. Then start using OpenCV (a cross-platform library for image processing) for doing serious work.

Comment: I agree with what you said, more than anything. But changing the platform is not something i can make decision on.

Comment: @karlphillip the source code suggest win32 BCB or BDS2006 Turbo C++ instead of ancient MS-DOS Turbo C++ ... the tags where wrong. Also this is VCL code so MSVCpp nor GCC would compile this ...

Answer (score 1):

There's several problem in the code that I can see immediately. The most striking comes from within the innermost for loop:

```
sum=0;
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
*Image = sum/4;
```

Here, you have simply added the same value to `sum` four times over, and then divided by four. This makes these six lines equivalent to

```
*Image = PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
```

Clearly, you actually wanted to average each channel. If your RGB image were implemented as a three-dimensional array, this would probably look something like:

```
sum = 0;
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ][ 0 ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ][ 1 ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ][ 2 ];
sum += PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ][ 3 ];
*Image = sum/4;
```

However, from your code example, it looks like your RGB image is actually implemented as a two-dimensional array of (un)signed integers. In that case, the following code should suffice (provided integers are four bytes on your machine):

```
sum = 0;
unsigned int pixel = PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[ i ][ j ];
for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
{
    sum += pixel & 0xFF;
    pixel >>= 1;
}
*Image = sum/4;
```

The other major problem I see is that you do not keep a pointer to the beginning of your grayscale array. You initialize it as

```
Image = new unsigned char[ 160 * 120 * 1 ];
```

which is good. But then each time through the loop, you've written

```
Image++;
```

Rather, you should keep a pointer to the beginning of the array, and have a temporary pointer which acts as an iterator:

```
// before the for loops
Image = new unsigned char[ 160 * 120 * 1 ];
unsigned char * temp = Image;

// at the end of the inner for loop:
temp++;
```

So you only move around the `temp` pointer, while `Image` stays fixed.

Comment: Oh I get the pointer part. But the average part i dun quite get it, becuase i have rgb value, each Pixels holds 4 values, x amt of red, x amt of blue, x amt of green, and lastly a NULL.

Comment: You say that each pixel holds 4 values. Are they stored inside a single unsigned int or something? How exactly is your image implemented?

Comment: You may want to match the luminance of the source RGB image in the destination grayscale image. Use the following standard formula:

Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B

Comment: @Ken, It is 
   mapHead.head.biSize = sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER );
   mapHead.head.biWidth = 160;
   mapHead.head.biHeight = 120;
   mapHead.head.biPlanes = 1;
   mapHead.head.biBitCount = 32;
   mapHead.head.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   mapHead.head.biSizeImage = 0;
   mapHead.head.biXPelsPerMeter = 1000;
   mapHead.head.biYPelsPerMeter = 1000;
   mapHead.head.biClrUsed = 0;
 mapHead.head.biClrImportant = 0;

 image = new unsigned char[ 160 * 120 * 4 ];
}
so the image size is 160width 120height and 4values per pixel.

@Hernan, wat does it mean by standard formula?

Comment: @Chang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity

Answer (score 0):

The **VCL** canvas use `TColor` to hold color. However internal format is defined by the `PixelFormat` format of the `Canvas` ... The usual is `pf32bit` or `pf24bit`... The `TColor` is always 32bit however regardless of the image `PixelFormat` as a lot of conversions happens along the way (that is why it is so slow) but beware different `PixelFormat` settings can reverse the RGB order making also predefined colors like `clYellow,...` reversed too (rendering as `clAqua,...`) !!!

For example if you use **VCL**s

```cpp
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
```

then each pixel is a 32bit value. You can do this safely for bitmaps but I am not sure about Form/PaintBox Canvas as they are tied to window I suspect your `PixelFormat` is similar (most likely 24bit) so you need to change your code slightly:

```cpp
int x,y,xs=160,ys=120;
DWORD rgb,bw;
Image = new unsigned char [ xs*ys*1 ];
for(y=0;y<ys;y++)
 for(x=0;x<xs;x++) 
    {
    rgb = PaintBox1->Canvas->Pixels[x][y];
    bw = ( rgb     &255) // sum r,g,b
        +((rgb>> 8)&255)
        +((rgb>>16)&255);
    bw/=3;               // normalize
    *Image = bw;         // write to your array
    Image++;
    bw*=0x00010101;      // convert intensity to grayscale RGB color (you can shift and or instead)
    PaintBox2->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]=TColor(bw); // write back
    } Image-=xs*ys;
```

The `Pixels` property is sloooow I would use VCL bitmap instead with use of its `ScanLine` property that is ~1000 and more times faster and also have load/save functions implemented so you can use bmp files easily. For more info see:

- [Graphics rendering in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

Also there are more ways to convert RGB to intensity see:

- [Problems with using a rough greyscale algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819333/2521214)