# View pixel intensities of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How to view the pixel intensities of an image in matlab by moving the mouse pointer over the image?

I used:

```
imshow(imread('image.jpg'));
```

But there is no option to view the pixel intensities of each pixel in the image.

For example,

```
      In MS-paint, while moving the mouse pointer 
      over the image we can see the location of 
      the pixel such as (20, 117) at the status bar.
```

But I need to see the pixel intensity instead.

Is there any other option to view it. Or I need to code to view it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `impixelinfo` and `impixelinfoval` for showing interactive information.

Answer (score 2):

One other option which is more interactive is

```
   imtool(imread('image.jpg')); % For GrayScale Image

   imtool(rgb2gray(imread('image.jpg')));  % For RGB Image
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an intensity map, you can use MATLAB's [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html). This will convert the n-by-m-by-3 RGB array you got from `imread` to an n-by-m matrix which contains the pixel intensities.

You can then point the [interactive data cursor](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) to this intensity matrix for the current mouse coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. I just typed two lines imshow(imread('image.jpg'));datacursormode on;                                                    Now By moving the cursor on the image the intensities are displayed along with the X,Y,Z coordinates.

Comment: @user2522560: oh wow, even simpler; did not know that :) Well, good for you! Remember that you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the big "tick" mark next to it.

Comment: For gray scale image it works, For RGB image we need to convert the image to rgb using rgb2gray and then proceed further like this imshow(rgb2gray(imread('image.jpg'))); datacursormode on; You are right. Thank you.