# Calculation of color position between black and white

Tags: java, opengl, colors, percentage

When you read this title you might automatically think of luminescence,
but that's not what I'm after.

What I want is to have you current color and have it wait on a scale from black to white.

So something like this [image: Color Scale], and then I would like the current color returned as a percentage of how black or white that color is.

Comment: already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was far simpler I kept over thinking this.

Basically just get RGB then get the highest color.

Then do `int ColorIntensity = (color / 255) * 100;` and that's basically your color intensity in percentage.

Answer (score 3):

There are different algorithms for converting colors to grayscales. [This](http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/grayscale/) is an explanation of an algorithm, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) on Grayscale might also lead you to useful ressources.

The implementation you finally choose highly depends on your use case.