# Detailed Calculation of RGB to Graylevel by Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, rgb, grayscale

I tried

```
ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]
```

to convert the **RGB to Graylevel**.
I am wondering the detailed calculation by mathematica..

```
Gray level= square(R^2+G^2+B^2)?
```

or something else?

Comment: related , tho not mathematica specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can obtain the exact values used by mathematica by making up a 3 pixel image with pure red,green,blue and converting it:

```
 lvec = First@
         ImageData[
           ColorConvert[Image[{{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}}], 
             "GrayScale"]]
```

> {0.299, 0.587, 0.114}

Note these are the "Rec. 601 luna coefficients" per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29

Test this on a real image:

```
 lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
 lenag = ColorConvert[lena, "GrayScale"];
 ImageData@ImageApply[ lvec.# & , lena ] == ImageData@lenag
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I convert colors to grayscale?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32036/363) for insight into how the calculation might be being done.

The two images produced by the commands below are a close match, but you could figure out the exact scaling vector with a short program making multiple comparisons.  A further test on a different image would ascertain whether `ColorConvert` uses the same vector all the time, or whether the image is analysed before conversion for an optimal grayscale appearance.

```
ColorConvert[img, "GrayScale"]

ImageApply[{0.35, 0.45, 0.2}.# &, img]
```

Comment: Aha...we can determine the exact calculation by ourselves..Tks so much.