# R raster - counting black pixels within an extent

Tags: r, image, image-processing, raster

My question is based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907919/r-raster-recognizing-black-color-raster-image). Answers on that page solved the problem that i was facing at that time. My new question is -

Below code plots two square on my image. For each square, I want to count how many black color pixels are within it.

My original questions answers suggests that I can flatten a RGB using `flat <- sum(x * c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140))`. In such case, I want to count pixels that have color value below 25.

I tried to leverage the answer suggested by the earlier post but couldnt figure out how to look within an extent.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
plotRGB(x)
plot(extent(c(0,20,0,20)), lwd=2, col="red", add=TRUE)
plot(extent(c(21,35,0,10)), lwd=2, col="Green", add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(raster)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
flat <- sum(x * c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140))
plot(flat, col=gray(seq(0,1,0.1)))
e1 <- extent(c(0,20,0,20))
e2 <- extent(c(21,35,0,10))
plot(e1, col='red', add=TRUE)
plot(e2, col='blue', add=TRUE)


# I am using a cut-off of 100 to get some cells below that threshold.
sum(extract(flat, e1) < 100)
sum(extract(flat, e2) < 100)

# for _very_ large files/extents this could be done to avoid RAM limitations
x <- crop(flat, e2)
y <- reclassify(x, matrix(c(-Inf, 100, 1, 100, Inf, 0), byrow=TRUE)) 
freq(y, value=1)
```

Comment: is there any purpose behind plotting image in gray scale - plot(flat, col=gray(seq(0,1,0.1)))? I replaced that command with plot(flat) and still got the same answer for last two commands..

Comment: plotting is only for plotting purposes. I used a gray scale to illustrate what you referred to with "black pixels"

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.