# crop image, convert to black and white and sharpen it

Tags: r, image, image-processing, colors, raster

I want to take x, convert it into a black and white image. Then i want to convert all pixels that are below 100 to 0 and convert all pixels that are above 100 to 255. I want to get a sharper image where background will be white and objects within image will be black. And then store new x (black and white sharp image) on my hard drive. How could i do it?

```
library(raster)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
plotRGB(x)
```

Based upon earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907919/r-raster-recognizing-black-color-raster-image), i wrote below lines to convert r1 to black and white. But plotRGB function fails :(. Plot function works but it doesnt return me a black and white image

```
flat <- sum(x * c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140))
plotRGB(flat)
flat
plot(flat)
```

========update1==========

in case anyone interested,

image colors can be swapped easily by using "1-twoclasses" in place of "twoclasses" in image and plot functions below

Comment: plotRGB does not fail. It is meant for a three layer Raster, not for a single layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually see grays you need to provide these colors.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
flat <- sum(x * c(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140))
plot(flat, col=gray(seq(0,1,0.1)))
```

You can use the reclassify function to get values that are either 0 or 255 but in this case it would seem more sensible to use 1 and 2

```
twoclasses <- cut(flat, c(0,100,255))
plot(twoclasses, col=gray(c(0,1)))
```

To write to disk, you can do something like:

```
png(width=ncol(twoclasses)*10, height=nrow(twoclasses)*10)
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
image(twoclasses, col=gray(c(0,1)))
dev.off()
```

Comment: I want to save the resulting black and white image as a jpg or png. How can i save the cropped image exactly at the same size. (size remains 50X50 pixels and I dont get legend and x and y axis and axis names/numbers - i get them after i run plot(twoclasses, col=gray(c(0,1))) ).

Comment: I have added a png writing example

Comment: thanks, any reason for changing width and height by 10x?

Comment: No. Just showing how you can adjust the size if the image would be too small.

Comment: thanks, any idea how i could smooth the image if i zoom it 10x (multiply height and width by 10 and then saved that image)?

Comment: plot(, interpolate=TRUE)

Comment: is there easy way to swap image colors? I want background to be black and actual image parts to be white