# Turning An Image GreyScale

Tags: java

Class 1
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Image {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "test.ppm";
    TestClass img = new TestClass(filename);

    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, img.getWidth());
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, img.getHeight());

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    img.display();

    System.out.println("Type anything then enter");
    keyboard.next();

    TestClass modified = new TestClass(filename);
    modified.removeReds();
    modified.display();
}
}
```

Class 2

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
private int width;
private int height;
private Color[][] data;

public TestClass(String filename) {
    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.out.println("Looked in " +
                System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Header information
    String format = fileIn.nextLine();
    width = fileIn.nextInt();
    height = fileIn.nextInt();
    int colorDepth = fileIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("File: " + filename + " is " + width
            + " x " + height + " pixels");

    // Verify file format
    if (!format.equals("P3") || colorDepth != 255) {
        System.out.println("Unknown format for file");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Read in data pixel by pixel
    data = new Color[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int red = fileIn.nextInt();
            int green = fileIn.nextInt();
            int blue = fileIn.nextInt();

            data[i][j] = new Color(red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}

public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(data[i][j]);
            StdDraw.point(j, height - i - 1);
        }
    }
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void removeReds() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            int red = data[i][j].getRed();
            int green = data[i][j].getGreen();
            int blue = data[i][j].getBlue();

            int sum = red+green+blue;
            Color newColor = new Color(sum / 3);



        }
    }
}
}
```

So i need to turnn this image greyscale. I know that you need to avg the red green and blue. I tried to but when every i run the program it just alters the colors making them a little darker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting RGB to grayscale/intensity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity)

Comment: I dont think i have a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's nowhere in your code where you actually modify the color of the pixels to the greyscale value. You can do this with the line `data[i][j] = newColor` in the for-loop in the `removeRed()` method (which should be called the `greyScale()` method). As it stands, you just find the greyscale color, then throw it away, and you also might be calculating it wrong.

Comment: yes but when i type in red + green + blue /3 that just makes the colors darker it doest turn it grey

Comment: can you upload the picture you are doing this with so I can see what your code does to it?

Comment: that's not a link, thats a filepath for the file on your personal computer