# How to convert RGB matrix to Grayscale array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, rgb, data-conversion, grayscale

I need an help to convert an array of rgb values (3 channels) into a single dimension grayscale array.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using some kind of graphics package?  If so it will likely have a conversion function built in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting RGB to grayscale/intensity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [PIL or Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) to hold your RGB values as an image, the conversion is trivial:

```
gray_image = rgb_image.convert('L')
```