# Showing change in a treemap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, treemap

I am trying to create this:

[image: Treemap in matplotlib]

The data for the chart is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "year": [2004, 2022, 2004, 2022, 2004, 2022],
    "countries" : [ "Denmark", "Denmark", "Norway", "Norway","Sweden", "Sweden",],
    "sites": [4,10,5,8,13,15]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df['diff'] = df.groupby(['countries'])['sites'].diff()
df['diff'].fillna(df.sites, inplace=True)

df
```

I am aware that there are packages that do treemaps, (squarify and plotly, to name some), but I have not figured out how to do the one above where the values of the years are added to each other. (or the difference to be exact) and it would be fantastic to learn how to do it in pure matplotlib, if it is not too complex.

Anyone has any pointers? I havent found a lot of info on treemaps on google.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to title your question, showing change in a treemap? That might be worth writing the whole algorithm yourself, or it might make it easier to find approaches in the existing libraries.

Comment: You are right,thanks and done

Comment: Deeper problem; if your series aren't all monotonic in the same direction, I don't believe you can use this. Notice that the solution below checks which value is larger at each time. But imagine that NorwayAfter is smaller than NorwayBefore: then the treemap division of the larger values is divided between two After values and one Before, and that probably isn't meaningful.

Comment: There's at least one thesis written on time series and treemaps! Great question. [Chintalapani thesis](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/items/b5638b93-b432-4762-877c-e2ccbe567823)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this task.

1. Computing a layout for the rectangles.
2. Drawing the rectangles.

The first part can get quite involved: people publish [scientific papers on the topic](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Evanwijk/stm.pdf). It's not advisable to re-invent the wheel here. However, the second part is quite straightforward and can be done in matplotlib.

The solution below uses squarify to compute a layout using the larger value for each value pair, and then matplotlib to draw two rectangles on top of each other.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import squarify

from matplotlib import colormaps
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

DEFAULT_COLORS = list(zip(colormaps["tab20"].colors[::2],
                          colormaps["tab20"].colors[1::2]))


def color_to_grayscale(color):
    # Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/689547/2912349
    r, g, b, a = to_rgba(color)
    return (0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b) * a


class PairedTreeMap:

    def __init__(self, values, colors=DEFAULT_COLORS, labels=None, ax=None, bbox=(0, 0, 200, 100)):
        """
        Draw a treemap of value pairs.

        values : list[tuple[float, float]]
            A list of value pairs.

        colors : list[tuple[RGBA, RGBA]]
            The corresponding color pairs. Defaults to light/dark tab20 matplotlib color pairs.

        labels : list[str]
            The labels, one for each pair.

        ax : matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes
            The matplotlib axis instance to draw on.

        bbox : tuple[float, float, float, float]
            The (x, y) origin and (width, height) extent of the treemap.

        """

        self.ax = self.initialize_axis(ax)
        self.rects = self.get_layout(values, bbox)
        self.artists = list(self.draw(self.rects, values, colors, self.ax))

        if labels:
            self.labels = list(self.add_labels(self.rects, labels, values, colors, self.ax))


    def get_layout(self, values, bbox):
        maxima = np.max(values, axis=1)
        order = np.argsort(maxima)[::-1]
        normalized_maxima = squarify.normalize_sizes(maxima[order], *bbox[2:])
        rects = squarify.padded_squarify(normalized_maxima, *bbox)
        reorder = np.argsort(order)
        return [rects[ii] for ii in reorder]


    def initialize_axis(self, ax=None):
        if ax is None:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_aspect("equal")
        ax.axis("off")
        return ax


    def _get_artist_pair(self, rect, value_pair, color_pair):
        x, y, w, h = rect["x"], rect["y"], rect["dx"], rect["dy"]
        (small, large), (color_small, color_large) = zip(*sorted(zip(value_pair, color_pair)))
        ratio = np.sqrt(small / large)
        return (plt.Rectangle((x, y), w,         h,         color=color_large, zorder=1),
                plt.Rectangle((x, y), w * ratio, h * ratio, color=color_small, zorder=2))


    def draw(self, rects, values, colors, ax):
        for rect, value_pair, color_pair in zip(rects, values, colors):
            large_patch, small_patch = self._get_artist_pair(rect, value_pair, color_pair)
            ax.add_patch(large_patch)
            ax.add_patch(small_patch)
            yield(large_patch, small_patch)
        ax.autoscale_view()


    def add_labels(self, rects, labels, values, colors, ax):
        for rect, label, value_pair, color_pair in zip(rects, labels, values, colors):
            x, y, w, h = rect["x"], rect["y"], rect["dx"], rect["dy"]
            # decide a fontcolor based on background brightness
            (small, large), (color_small, color_large) = zip(*sorted(zip(value_pair, color_pair)))
            ratio = small / large
            background_brightness = color_to_grayscale(color_large) if ratio < 0.33 else color_to_grayscale(color_small) # i.e. 0.25 + some fudge
            fontcolor = "white" if background_brightness < 0.5 else "black"
            yield ax.text(x + w/2, y + h/2, label, va="center", ha="center", color=fontcolor)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    values = [
        (4, 10),
        (13, 15),
        (5, 8),
    ]

    colors = [
        ("red", "coral"),
        ("royalblue", "cornflowerblue"),
        ("darkslategrey", "gray"),
    ]

    labels = [
        "Denmark",
        "Sweden",
        "Norway"
    ]

    PairedTreeMap(values, colors=colors, labels=labels, bbox=(0, 0, 100, 100))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe test for monotonicity of the dataseries before plotting anything and warn if they aren't all the same direction. I think the treemap is the wrong layout for that case. If they *are* all the same direction, the inner code is easier and adding a  legend is too.

Comment: @cphlewis The changes don't need to be all in the same direction, as long as the colors are well chosen. I think the different saturation levels do an alright job at indicating before/after.

Comment: Though I agree that it wouldn't necessarily be my visualization of choice either for paired data, unless I also cared about the total volume as well (in which case all pairs better be monotonically increasing, so point taken, I guess).

Comment: I figured it wasnt an easy answer as I havent seen many results on treemaps. Thanks! I will review the code to see if I can make sense of it.

The visualization has been taken from 100datavizproject website where they try to visualize 1 datasaet in 100 different ways, regardless of the effectiveness of the viz. I am just trying to recreate them all to learn matplotlib.