# How mat2gray works in matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, scale, matlab-guide

I want to understand how mat2gray works? I mean back end work and formula etc. then I want to scale the image using it so that it follows the format, 0 for max value and 255 for min value.

Anyone, please suggest me a formula to convert uint16 depth image in the range 0 to 255.but 0 for max value of depth and 255 for min value of depth

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311774/why-does-greyscale-work-the-way-it-does

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how `mat2gray` works, you can open the function file within MATLAB by highlighting the function name and pressing Ctrl+D, which will open the file in the MATLAB editor so you can view the source code (side note: this doesn't work with all MATLAB functions, as a lot are "built-in" functions).

To change the image as you're requesting, you'd simply do the following:

```
I = (1-I)*255;
```

Comment: can u explain how u r formula will work ? since my image is uint16.. its range is 0 to 65536.but  my camera depth value range is 0 to 8000. now  i want to map it in 0 to 255 range and mapping as 0 for maxVal and 255 for minVal

Comment: If you use `mat2gray`, it normalizes the matrix to between 0-1, with the max being at 1 and the min at 0. You can invert this by doing `1-I`, and then scale it to 0-255 by multiplying by 255.